# AS3 Making a button work on one scene and does nothing on all other scenes.

Tags: actionscript-3

I basically have 50 buttons and 50 scenes. Each scene has a corresponding button that is "correct". When a user clicks the correct button, I want it to go to the next scene AND also make that button not-clickable anymore. I have everything functioning except for the not-clickable part and this is an issue because whenever i click on a state that already has been selected as the right answer, it'll jump me back to the question that was supposed to follow it. I'd show my code, but it is just 50 buttons and a buttonClick function and that's it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend sharing the minimal amount of code necessary that showcases the issue for us to better understand the issue at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You could call

```
yourButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,yourFunction);
```

or you could call

```
yourButton.mouseEnabled = false;
yourButton.mouseChildren = false;
```

Hard to help without any code.